# Access Shared Google Sheets in Microsoft Azure App

Tags: azure, google-sheets, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm trying to access a shared google sheet for my Logic app. The documentation mentions there's a workaround in the "previous step" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/googlesheet/), but I cannot seem to find where that previous step is. Does anyone have the link the that piece of the documentation?

I've tried going back using the breadcrumb menu at the top, but nothing mentions this work around.